# Ruby use hash in 'do' loop

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

I have a code which looks like this:

```
hash = {
     1000 => "john",
     1001 => "mary",
}

list = File.foreach("list.txt").map { |line| line.split('  ') }

out = list.each do |(file, user, time)|
     puts "Some plain text #{file}, #{user}, #{time}"
end
```

In #{user} I get a number which can be 1000 or 1001.

My question is, how can I access info from hash to be able to put it instead of #{user}. In my understanding final output should look like this.

> Some plain text, file.txt, john, 00:00

I was thinking about doing it like this, but it didn't worked.

```
puts "Some plain text #{file}, hash[user], #{time}"
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What does `list.txt` look like?

Comment: 12:59-04/06/2016-UTC /tmp/file6.txt 1000 - only such entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string interpolation (as you have done for `file` and `time`), it works for any valid Ruby expression.

```
puts "Some plain text #{file}, #{hash[user]}, #{time}"
```

Comment: Note the hash's keys are integers.